# Postman tests hang when running from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, postman-collection-runner

When running postman/newman test collection from Azure DevOps, the tests hang. The output says:

```
[debug]INPUT_SCRIPT: 'newman run CVueAPITests.postman_collection.json -k -e QME.postman_environment.json -d CVUEAPIAliveData_1.csv --reporters junit --reporter-junit-export Results\junitReport.xml'
[debug]INPUT_WORKINGDIRECTORY: 'D:\DEV_agent\_work\7\s\Postman\CVue'
[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'D:\DEV_agent\_work\7\s\Postman\CVue'
Generating script.
Script contents:
newman run CVueAPITests.postman_collection.json -k -e QME.postman_environment.json -d CVUEAPIAliveData_1.csv --reporters junit --reporter-junit-export Results\junitReport.xml
[debug]AGENT_VERSION: '2.149.2'
[debug]AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY: 'D:\DEV_agent\_work\_temp'
[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'D:\DEV_agent\_work\_temp'
[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
[debug] Arguments: '/D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\DEV_agent\_work\_temp\1c3a85e8-d01b-4df3-b6b0-322239c48093.cmd""'
[debug] FileName: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'
[debug] WorkingDirectory: 'D:\DEV_agent\_work\7\s\Postman\CVue'
[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\DEV_agent\_work\_temp\1c3a85e8-d01b-4df3-b6b0-322239c48093.cmd""
```

I have no issues running the test collection when I execute this exact same command locally on the build server:

```
newman run CVueAPITests.postman_collection.json -k -e QME.postman_environment.json -d CVUEAPIAliveData_1.csv --reporters junit --reporter-junit-export Results\junitReport.xml
```

Comment: Hi,how is your problem progressing?If you have any question,feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it according to this [blog](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/how-to-configure-postman-newman-api-tests-in-azure-devops-or-tfs-and-publish-html-results-caf60a25c8b9) , and finally I can successfully get the test results. You can refer to it for detailed guide.

Here I give a detailed configuration,you can see where it is different from yours.Hope can help you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I had followed the same blog initially but still no dice.  I have tried adding/removing "cli" to the **--reporters** flag but it seems as though the test are not being launch because nothing is reported back to the "Run API Tests" build step console log.

Comment: You use private agent. You can go to the Results folder under the local s folder to see if there is a junitReport.xml file generated.